# Cannot get IP forwarding work in docker container

Tags: networking, docker, router

I am wanting to set up a playground to test some nftables firewall rules before I put them on a real router. Docker containers seem to be good lightweight instrument for this. A prerequisite of this test is that one of the containers needs to work as a router for the others. I have no issues making a Linux box a router when it is bare metal (or fully virtualized). But when it is a docker container, it does not work.

So, I create 2 networks, `tmp_21` and `tmp_22`:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.21.0.0/16 --gateway=172.21.0.1 tmp_21
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.22.0.0/16 --gateway=172.22.0.1 tmp_22
```

Create router box, making it attached to both the above networks:

```
docker run \
--name tmp_router -h tmp_router \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=SYS_MODULE \
--sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1 --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0 \
--net tmp_21 --ip 172.21.0.20 \
-it debian /bin/bash

# On the host machine:
docker network connect tmp_22 tmp_router --ip 172.22.0.20
```

Create 2 test boxes, one in each network:

```
docker run \
--name tmp_box21 -h tmp_box21 \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
--net tmp_21 --ip 172.21.0.21 \
-it debian /bin/bash

docker run \
--name tmp_box22 -h tmp_box22 \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
--net tmp_22 --ip 172.22.0.22 \
-it debian /bin/bash
```

From this point both boxes can ping the router on 172.21.0.20 and 172.22.0.20 respectively.

Now I want to make `tmp_box21` to be able to ping `tmp_box22`. Within `tmp_box21` I add this route:

```
ip route add 172.22.0.0/16 via 172.21.0.20
```

From this point, `tmp_box21` can ping the router not only on 172.21.0.20 but on 172.22.0.20 as well.

However, that does not enable it to ping `tmp_box22` on 172.22.0.22!

Why?

Note that the output of `nft list ruleset` on the router is empty.

Comment: Backwards-route 172.21.0.0/16 via 172.22.0.22 is missing. I'm sure tmp_box22 gets the ping packets, but the backroute is failing

Comment: @stoney That's it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this question was solved, you should make an answer to it (telling what you had to do to get it working and accepting it 2 days later) or else delete it.

Comment: @A.B I think the question with the first 2 comments is useful as is already. Feel free to duplicate the comments in an answer if you like and I'll accept it. I may do it myself if I feel like it but I deny that I _should_ as you say.

Comment: It should be either @stoney or you. I should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backwards-route 172.21.0.0/16 via 172.22.0.22 is missing. I'm sure tmp_box22 gets the ping packets, but the backroute is failing